# How to send push notification to a specific User using Pusher in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, pusher

I need to send a push notification to a specific user using pusher beams and I dont need to send a push using channel, I need to send **Push notification for a particular user using USER ID for both iOS and Android** and I have already done this in iOS in swift using **PUSHER BEAMS** but I dont get any reference for this in official pusher documentation to do this in **react-native** so kindly let me know anyone is there any way to send the push to a particular user by using the user ID with Pusher in react native?